# Using Spotify API to Display User Top Artists

Tags: reactjs, spotify, spotify-app

```js
let topArtists;

spotify.getMyTopArtists().then((artists) => {
   topArtists = artists.items;
   console.log(topArtists);
}, (err) => {
   console.log('Error:', err);
});

return (
   <div className="test">
      <h1>{}</h1>
   </div>
);
```

I am currently able to display a User's top artists in the console as shown in the code above, however, I am wondering what I need to put in the return to be able to display the top artists on the actual webpage and not in the console.

Answer (score 1):

Use State to hold the values, then you can map over your state to display.
I have included the code to add artists to state.

```
import React { useState } from "react";

function App() {
 
  const [topArtists, setTopArtists] = useState([]);


  spotify.getMyTopArtists().then((artists) => {
     setTopArtists((prevEntries) => {
      return [artists.items, ...prevEntries];
    });
  }, (err) => {
    console.log('Error:', err);

};
```